# Copying a file from a server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am currently trying to copy a file from a server to a local file. Below is my current code. I am currently generating the following error, [Errno 13] Permission denied. I believe this is associated with the remote path. Any ideas?

```
import os
import paramiko 
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='de.ac.uk', username="hfseb", password="kjsvbkjcb")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
localpath = '/Users/abc/def'
remotepath = '/home/abc/def/game.log'
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Error generated
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\abc\python\ssh1.py", line 15, in 
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)

File "C:\Users\abc\python\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 759, in put
return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)

File "C:\Users\abc\python\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 714, in putfo
with self.file(remotepath, "wb") as fr:

File "C:\Users\abc\python\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)

File "C:\Users\abc\python\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
return self._read_response(num)

File "C:\Users\abc\python\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
self._convert_status(msg)

File "C:\Users\abc\python\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 896, in _convert_status
raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)

Comment: `/Users/abc/def` seems like a path to a folder, while `/home/abc/def/game.log` seems like a path to a file. That seems like a mismatch. 1) What are you trying to achieve? 2) Show us an exception callstack.

Comment: I am attempting to copy that file from the server to the local folder.

Comment: Can you upload that local file to that remote folder using any commandline/GUI SFTP client which run on the same machine as your Python code and uses the same credentials? Show us its log file.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the remote **def** directory have wrong permissions.